# import cannot be resolved: import com.google.android.maps.*;

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I was successfully using google maps in my application but then needed to change the Android SDK version from 1.5 to 2.0.  Now the import for Google maps can't be resolved.

Comment: Is ` import com.google.android.maps.*;` exactly what you're importing? You can't use wildcard import

Comment: No, I only included the wild card here for simplicity.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Make sure you have

```
<uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

in your application manifest, and that you've downloaded not just the 2.0 SDK but the 2.0-with-google-APIs SDK. Then set your project's properties in Eclipse to check off the Google APIs version of the SDK you want. Then try to clean your build (Project-> Clean in eclipse; "ant clean" from the command line).

Answer (score 15):

adding google-play-services.jar to my project's path solved my problem.

right click project->properties->java build path-> libraries tab -> add external jar

browse to android-sdk folder->extras\google\google-play-services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs\

If you don't have google-play-services folder then you need to close eclipse and open up the SDK manager separately and download google-play.

If you already downloaded google-play and still don't see your google-play-services folder, then you need to search for it....chances are that you have multiple android sdks installed....

Answer (score 13):

1.Install all google API's using sdk manager.

2.In your manifest,under application element add

```
     <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

3.You have to include jar file for maps also..
Right click on your project and go to build path and then add external archives.
locate your sdk. android-sdk-windows\add-ons\addon_google_apis_google_inc_8\libs\maps

Comment: Keep in mind that the location for this jar is for the deprecated version of Android maps, use the answer by `user852415` for the new location.

Answer (score 4):

Doing right-click Properties->Android and selecting a Target Name **Google APIs** instead of Android x.x fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Add
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'

in dependency section of your build.gradle

Comment: Consider adding a backtick (\`, the ~ key without shift) around "compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'" to format it as code, `like so`.

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to add google-play-services_lib to the project's list of libraries. Doing so resolved this issue for me.

Right-click project->properties->Android

Click the 'Add...' button found to the right of the Library Reference/Project table.

If you have downloaded the Google Play Services Library with the SDK Manager, you should see the library as a choice in the Project Selection box that pops up when you press the Add button.

If you have not downloaded Google Play Services follow the instructions here:
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html